# Convert multiple bytes array into single long variable

Tags: c, 8051

Im getting 10 bytes of data in an char array like which contains hex value
Data1[0] = 0x00,Data1[1] = 0x00,Data1[0] = 0x9 Data1[2]=0x01and so on...
Now I want to get this different array bytes into single long variable . Like

Long_var = 091...
How can do it any method can be accepted.

Sorry, i forgot to mention, i want to do this in 8051 code

Comment: 10 bytes is 80 bits, so it doesn't fit into any variable that an 8051 compiler would support. Unless 8051 compilers support 128-bit variables these days.

Comment: This is an XY problem: you want to (de)serialize an octetstream. Use shifts and bitops and let the compiler optimise (just follow a common pattern);

Answer (score 2):

There are generally two ways to do [*type punning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) in C, both involving arrays.

The first is to use a plain array of 32-bit integers, and then copy the bytes into that array:

```
char data[12];
// data is initialized...

uint32_t integers[3];
memcpy(integers, data, 12);

printf("First value is 0x%08x\n", integers[0]);
```

The other way is to use unions:

```
union type_punning_union
{
    uint32_t integers[3];
    char data[12];
};

union type_punning_union u;
// Initialize u.data...

printf("First value is 0x%08x\n", u.integers[0]);
```

**Big important note 1:** Your byte array have a size mismatch for matching all data evenly to 32-bit integers.

**Big important note 2:** The code shown above doesn't care about [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), meaning the results printed might not be exactly what you expect.

Comment: Both are bad approaches for the actual problem: (un)marshalling/serialisation. Use bitops and shifts; a good compiler could create highly opotimised code for the platform.